# jquery set image size on click of button

Tags: php, jquery

i am working on image upload and i there is option to select size of image in inches and centimeters. when user select inches its div display with buttons that have size like 15*12, 30*20 and when user select centimeters then div comes 38cm*28cm, 78cm * 56cm. div's are coming  on click of inch and centimeter buttons. but how i can set the size according to selected button. i want that when user select 15*12 then image comes with this size in div. This is code to show and hide div of inches and centimeters.

```
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');

    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the content from botton and
To set image size-

```
$("#imageID").attr("width",width);
$("#imageID").attr("height",height);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's completely legal to set width and height with different units such as inches and centimeters.  All you do is say `"3in"` for 3 inches, or `"10cm"` for 10 centimeters.  (You can do this in both CSS and jQuery.)

```
/* valid CSS */
img {
    width: 3in;
}
```

```
// valid jQuery
$("img").width("3in");
```

Here's some simple HTML and jQuery to see how you can set the size of something in reaction to a click event.

```
<img id="myImg" src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="...">
<button data-width="15in" data-height="20in">15 x 20</button>
<button data-width="20in" data-height="30in">20 x 30</button>
```

```
// Every time a <button> is clicked, resize the image to the dimensions
// given in the data-width and data-height attributes.
$("button").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    $("#myImg").width( $button.data("width") ).height( $button.data("height") );
});
```

Comment: Is there any data-width and data-height attributes of button? for me its not working when i click on button.

Comment: You can add `data-*` attributes to any element.  It's just a convenient way of associating arbitrary data to an element.